# Ubuntu не подключается к Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

Друзья! Мой вопрос не имеет непосредственного отношения к программированию, но все же я надеюсь, что меня не закидают из-за этого камнями, а предложат какой-нибудь выход. Очень прошу вас об этом. Проблема заключается в следующем. Установил на свой ноутбук операционную систему Ubuntu. Все отлично работает, но стоит мне куда-то отойти, компьютер погружается в сон и после того, как я его разбужу больше не подключается к Wi-Fi. При том, что первое подключение к сети сразу после загрузки ОС выполняется успешно и сама сеть видна в списке. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Отключите управлением питанием Wi-Fi карточки.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade